# Qt KDE theme stylesheet

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma

I am using KDE theme Breeze Dark. Since all my Qt applications have changed its colors. Earlier my applications wasn't altered by KDE themes but now I am receiving message: "kf5.kiconthemes: "Theme tree: (Breeze)". I was changing background colors in my apps using stylesheets. Now due to changed fonts colors it is impossible to read (white text on very bright background). What is more I am not able to get default background color.

qDebug() << qApp->styleSheet(); gives me empty string.

How to get background color? I would like to use it setting my own backgrounds (showing priority of a task, little more reddish background and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access to default theme colors via QPalette.

If you want just to change colors of your widgets - QSS is overkill. QPalette is more than enough.